# Python Selenium Open Whatsapp Without Using Qr Code Every TIme

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, whatsapp

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from config import CHROME_DATA_PATH

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument(CHROME_DATA_PATH)


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")

time.sleep(10)
driver.quit()
```

I have been trying to make a WhatsApp bot by using selenium. I have almost tried every way to open WhatsApp without using a QR code every time. But I couldn't figure out why it's not working. Most of the solutions were written by executable_path method which is not working currently.

I also have tried using it by opening a specific browser. But then I encountered an error:

```
C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Profile 1")
chrome_service = Service(executable_path = r'chromedriver.exe')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = chrome_service, options = option)
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
time.sleep(20)
```

**Once you login to your Whatsapp account by using code your login data will be automatically save to AppData. You should use a chromedriver so program can save data to it.**